# Nodejs async/await for MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I trying to execute 2 MySQL queries sequentially in Node.JS. MySQL queries work properly by itself.
I would like to do it with async/await function to be sure record is inserted before it's updated. 
Here is the code:

```
router.post('/assign_new_item_id', async (req, res) => {
   .....
   try {
      let qr1= "INSERT INTO foo1 ........;"              
      await pool.query( qr1, (err) => {
         if (err) throw err;
      });
      let qr2= "UPDATE foo1 .....;"
      await pool.query( qr2, (err) => {
         if (err) throw err;
      });
   }catch(err){
     console.log(err)
}
```

It seems that execution "hangs" within  first await await block. What is the best way the ensure that both queries are executed consequently.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To `await` you need a Promise, Not Callback. In your case you are not returning a promise to await.

```
router.post('/assign_new_item_id', async (req, res) => {
    // .....
    try {
        let qr1 = "INSERT INTO foo1 ........;"
        await new Promise((res, rej) => {
            pool.query(qr1, (err, row) => {
                if (err) return rej(err);
                res(row);
            });
        });
        let qr2 = "UPDATE foo1 .....;"
        await new Promise((res, rej) => {
            pool.query(qr2, (err, row) => {
                if (err) return rej(err);
                res(row);
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Here I am promisifing the `pool.query` method and returning a promise.

Comment: That works. Thanks. I have a question though, in another project i execute several MySQL delete queries in sequence with await but without Promise. And that worked as expected. Is there a difference base on the type of the query i.e. insert vs. delete?